# Polylongdivision add factors next to the steps

Tags: math-mode, polynom

Well for example, take

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}


\polylongdiv{x^3 - 7x -6}{x + 1}


\end{document}
```

I wish the function to display clearly next to each partial division "x2, -x & -6".

Edit: I think the desired layout is:

[image]

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: changed.. but really mathjax should just be installed for these things. But the extra information really is just noise: it contains no data as I already said using polynom package, and it is independent on the documentclass. So the new codepiece doesn't follow DRY principles.

Comment: @paul23: See [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1272/5764)

Comment: What is a 'DRY principle'? In any case, complete code makes it easier for people to help you - copy-paste-compile-play - and providing it is therefore a courtesy which saves needless duplication of effort, and increases the chances somebody will help you. (If it is quicker/easier.more interesting to help, people are more likely to help.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself - never state the same thing twice, or type something extra which can be automated.

Comment: @paul23 people offering to help are not automated they are humans and it helps to give them a working test file rather than make them write one from scratch.

Comment: so you just want the monomials from the top line copying down? But where to? on the left or right?  all vertically aligned or staggered to the right to match the existing layout or.... ? It would be clearer if you uploaded an image of the example annotated with where you want factors adding (I can't guess where they can be placed without disturbing the working?)

Comment: Well I've always learned to put those as a simple "list"  to the right of the division, basically as another column. (and top should just show the whole division, not sure what that thingy at the left is doing there)

Comment: I ask again you post an annotated image, as i am not at all sure what you mean. Or what "thingy" you find unexpected in the existing output. there is a _lot_ of cultral variation in long division layout, see http://www.w3.org/Math/draft-spec/chapter3.html#presm.mlongdiv.ex

Comment: I added an image of what I _think_ you mean. If that's wrong please replace it.

Comment: Nope that's correct (but then aligned well, which is giving me headaches everywhere) - Also when I do it on paper I typically add a vertical line, which adds a corner to the topline.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be what you seek?  Based on your comment to David, I added a corner and drop line to the topline.  I then used a `\Longunderstack` (which gives lines with evenly spaced baselines (here set to 13.5pt gap), set downward from the top row, in order to set the right column.

If necessary in other cases, you could wrap the `\Longunderstack` in a `\raisebox` to effect a vertical shift of the right column numbers for fine tuning.

In this case, I empirically determined the 13.5pt baseline skip, but I presume, considering 2 rows plus an underline as a grouping, that 2(13.5pt) = 2\baselineskip + "underline gap."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{13.5pt}
\begin{document}
\polylongdiv{x^3 - 7x -6}{x + 1} 
\rule[-4pt]{2ex}{.4pt}%
\rule[\dimexpr-4pt-8\baselineskip\relax]{.4pt}{8\baselineskip}
\Longunderstack[r]{\\ \\ $x^2$\\  \\ $-x$\\  \\ $-6$}
\end{document}
```

[image]